# How to convert an org-mode outline into a Microsoft Word outline?

Tags: org-mode, outline, ms-word

The title of this post says it all: I have an outline in an org-mode file, and I want to convert it to a Microsoft Word document that I can open in "outline view"<sup>1</sup>.

Unfortunately, the Microsoft Word requirement is non-negotiable in this case; it's mandated by my employer as company-wide policy.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Or maybe it's "outline mode", or some such; I'm not very sure of Word's terminology for its outlining support, but I know it has it.</sup>

Comment: Does exporting to ODT and then producing a `doc` or `docx` file from Libre Office do what you want? Or perhaps using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert?

Comment: Also copy pasting and exported html to a word document might be enough.